# Repeating Loop on my Posts Page

Tags: loop

I have a problem with my `loop.php`, it keeps on repeating posts. I'm guessing this might be controlled outside of this `loop.php` as it happens no matter what I try. Could someone please advise me as to where it might be getting this information to repeat the loop 4 times.

Here is the current `loop.php`

```
<?php 
    $args = array ( 'category' => 4, 'posts_per_page' => 10);
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);

    ?>

    <!-- Begin Style Here -->

    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <div class="postmeta">
            <?php do_action('themezee_display_postmeta_index'); ?>
        </div>

        <h2 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

        <div class="entry">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'alignleft')); ?>
            <?php the_content('<span class="moretext">' . __('Read more', 'themezee_lang') . '</span>'); ?>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="postinfo">
            <?php do_action('themezee_display_postinfo_index'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- End Style Here -->

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thanks for any help with this

Comment: What do you mean by "repeating posts": are they all identical in this foreach loop? Do you have more than 4 posts assigned to  this category?

Answer (score 1):

In order not to interfere with main `wp_query` I would recommend to use this hook, that I used on one of my websites.

```
//wp_query to buffer
$temp_query = clone $wp_query;

//Use main wp_query with attributes
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 10 ) ); 
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
//your code with html and etc    
endwhile; endif;

//Get back to main wp_query
$wp_query = clone $temp_query;
```

Comment: Where do I insert this? into my code on the loop.php?

Comment: My index.php I'm thinking is the issue and maybe why all the posts are repeated 4 times.

Comment: This is most of my current index.php and I believe the problem

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' );
endwhile; ?><?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { // if PageNavi is activated ?><div class="more_posts"><?php wp_pagenavi(); ?></div><?php } else { // Otherwise, use traditional Navigation ?>
<div class="more_posts"><span class="post_links"><?php next_posts_link(__('&laquo; Older Entries', 'themezee_lang')) ?> &nbsp; <?php previous_posts_link (__('Recent Entries &raquo;', 'themezee_lang')) ?></span>
</div><?php }?><?php endif; ?>